# Most voted questions of the week?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, filtering, question-lists

I know how to get all questions of the week:

- select the 'questions→newest' tab and go down the list.

I know how to get the most voted questions ever:

- select the 'questions→votes' tab and go down the list.

How come it's not possible to get a summary of recent¹ *and* interesting questions directly² on the site, or is it?

—
<sup>1. Depending on the SE site, sometimes I would rather have a look at interesting questions of the month (or the day).</sup>
<sup>2. Newsletters are not always available, impractical and only contain 5 entries. And SQL queries are… SQL queries…</sup>

Comment: [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I've been taking this feature for granted in the 10k tools. But I do agree it should be available to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incredible, this feature request has been implemented. I just noticed tabs "week" and "month" that are accessible directly from the "homepage", and votes on answers even seem to be taken into account! Wow excellent!

Duh, for how long has this been available? It's not even listed in the [Changelog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)…

Comment: [That weekly and monthly hot post tabs have existed forever](http://web.archive.org/web/20081004141246/http://stackoverflow.com/?sort=month). I also somehow didn't notice it until recently.

Comment: @TheElementofMagic: It might have been hidden with some css. I did check the homepage when I wrote this question… Hum… did I? :-)

Comment: You may have checked the "Questions" tab, instead of the home page. That's what I did!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember the homepage having only three tabs, not so long ago. Unfortunately I can't find a version on the web archive from early 2012.

Answer (score 4):

The weekly highest voted answers would be a lot more interesting to me.

Comment: Yes right, ideally the vote count should take into account votes on answers too!